# How to redirect using 'if'

Tags: php, html

I want to check the variables of a form. here I want "a" and "b" to be numbers betwen 5 and 99. if that is true I want to automaticly redirect to the next page, if not to remain to this page.

Let me explain by showing the piece of code i made:
(i am sorry but i spent 15 minutes to understand how to write code here and i don't understand so i will use spaces when necesary)

```
<input type="text" name="a"><br>
<input type="text" name="b"><br>
<input type="submit" value="GO!">

<?php
if (is_numeric($_POST["a"]) && is_numeric($_POST["b"]) && 
$_POST["a"]<100 && $_POST["a"]>4 && $_POST["b"]<100 && $_POST["b"]>4) {
  echo "corect";
  //here i want to go to the next page like registration_complete.php
}
else {
  //here i want to remain to this page and show the errors to the user
}
?>
```

I am sorry for this probably simple question but i find only stupid answers on google.

Comment: `header("Location: my_page.php"); exit();` to redirect where you echo "corect"

Comment: Wont work since he is outputting content before.

Comment: That's true the headers are alrady sent when he comes to send new headers. As such he should move the PHP code to the top of the page.

Answer (score 2):

First you must check it before you echo something. Then use `header("Location: mylogin_page.php");`. 
 What the point to echo something when you have chance that user will not see it? Then use header BEFORE html output.

Comment: Since he has HTML output before, this will fail with an Headers Already Sent error

Comment: i understand that echo is usless there...

Comment: @Point89: it's not about `echo`, it's about your `input` tags at the beginning. Sure `echo` shouldn't be there either.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are already outputting content to the screen, you cannot use the `header('Location: mypage.php')`. If you can't or don't want to do this, an alternative would be to use a javascript redirect:

```
echo "<script>document.location.replace = 'mypage.php';</script>";
```

Comment: Good solution, maybe add `type="text/javascript"` to the the `script`-tag, just to have it. :)

Comment: Dont need for dirty things. Just change logic a bit

Comment: Sure - I'm more interested in the concept, not his version of HTML :)

Comment: @DenisErmolin I agree! But sometimes it's not as simple as that. I am currently working on a system where it would take hours and hours of works to change it to do this. Sometimes dirty is the only choice :(

Comment: Change what? Write some code before any output?

Comment: Well the code he provide is already dirty with PHP and HTML all mixed up, specially since he only provide a tiny tiny part of his code we can't just assume that it is easy to change were the output starts. Maybe the file is just included somewhere where already something is put out, maybe not.

Comment: It's not as simple as that when there are hundreds of files, included at various points, hacked over a decade, with dependencies all over the place.

Comment: thak you but I never used java...

Comment: @LeonardChallis: OP doesn't know how to do freaking redirect. Do you think that his system has hundreds of files? **Read** his comment and let it **sink**!

Comment: @SilentGhost Nope, however I offered an answer to the question, both for him and people finding the post via google who might need an alternative to doing it via PHP. And I clearly referred to that first.

Comment: @LeonardChallis: thanks! youre logic is right. I want to do it using php/html not include java or other stuff...

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can't use `header` after you send any html code to the browser, so your php code should be in another file so you should have:

`first-step.php` which contains:

```
<?php
   session_start();
?>
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
   <?php
      if(isset($_SESSSION['error'])) {
         echo $_SESSION['error'];
         unset($_SESSION['error']);
      }
   ?>
   <form action="actions.php?step=1" method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="a"><br>
     <input type="text" name="b"><br>
     <input type="submit" value="GO!">
   </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

`actions.php`

```
<?php
  session_start();

  switch($_GET['step']) {
     case 1:
       if(is_numeric($_POST["a"]) && is_numeric($_POST["b"]) && $_POST["a"]<100 && $_POST["a"]>4 && $_POST["b"]<100 && $_POST["b"]>4)
       {
         header('Location: second-step.php');
         exit;
       }
       else
       {
         $_SESSION['error'] = 'my error';
         header('Location: first-step.php');
       }
     break;
   }
?>
```

Comment: the ideea with difrent files makes sens. Thank you! (mersi!)

Comment: Welcome :) (cu placere!)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if (is_numeric($_POST["a"]) && is_numeric($_POST["b"]) && $_POST["a"]<100 && $_POST["a"]>4 && $_POST["b"]<100 && $_POST["b"]>4)
    {
        header('location:correctpage.php');
    }
    else
    {
      foreach($POST as $key=>$post)
     {
       if(empty($post))
      {
        $error [] ="$key is empty required";//do your custom error handling this is just a demo
      }
        print_r($error);
        //here i want to remain to this page and show the errors to the user
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="a"><br/>
<input type="text" name="b"><br/>    
<input type="submit" value="GO!">    

<?php    
if (is_numeric($_POST["a"]) && is_numeric($_POST["b"]) && 
$_POST["a"]<100 && $_POST["a"]>4 && $_POST["b"]<100 && $_POST["b"]>4) {
  //echo "corect"; //why 'echo' then redirect?
  echo "<script>";
  echo "top.location = 'registration_complete.php';";
  echo "</script>";
  exit();
}    
else {
  //here i want to remain to this page and show the errors to the user
  //(if you want so, just stay executing this page)
}    
?>
```

Comment: i don't understand. youre script dosen't do anything...